# If x and y are real numbers such that y-x>1 then there is an integer z such that x<=z<=y

Tags: real-analysis

So, we made this proof in class but I am not sure I follow, this is the proof.

Let's consider $|x| \ge 0$, since $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded then

$|x| < n $ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow-n<x<n$

$ \therefore \exists$ just a finite numbers $l\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $-n<l<x$

let m = max{ l | -n< l < x }

$\therefore m<x,\ m+1\not<x\Rightarrow m+1\ge x$

On the other hand, if $m < x$ then $m+1 < x + 1$ and $y>1+x$

so $x<m+1<x+1<y$

naming z = m+1 we get

$x\le z<y$

$Q.E.D$

The parts that are not clear to me are de 4th and 5th lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the fourth and fifth lines as follows:

For the fourth line, Consider the set $\{l|-n<l<x\}$. Clearly this set is nonempty since there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$. Therefore, for any such $n$, we have that there are a finite number of $l$ such that $-n<l<x$. So choose the largest such $l$ for any given $n$. This is equivalent to the greatest $l$ such that $l<x$. We will call this $m=\max\{l|-m<l<x\}$.

For the fifth line, it follows if $m$ is the greatest integer less than $x$, then $m+1$ must be greater than or equal to $x$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, this is not true. Then $m+1<x$. But this would imply $m+1\in \{l|-n<l<x\}$. Not only this, but since $m+1>m$, $m$ is not the max of this set, a contradiction. Therefore, $m<x\leq m+1$.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation by contradiction was clear enough, I wasn't getting why would m+1 be greater than x.

Comment: @Darwin57721 Thank you! I appreciate the review.