# If x and y are real numbers such that $y-x>1$ then there is an integer m such that $x\leq m\leq y$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, integers

As a homework a proof is needed using Archimedes and integer function

For $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$

If $y-x > 1$ then $∃ m ∈ Z:  x\leq m\leq y$$

I've found this [If x and y are real numbers such that y-x>1 then there is an integer z such that x<=z<=y](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933113/if-x-and-y-are-real-numbers-such-that-y-x1-then-there-is-an-integer-z-such-that)
but does not seem exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be the biggest integer that $m\leq y$. Then $y-m<1$, so $$x+1-m<y-m<1$$ and thus $x<m$.

Comment: you didn't use the integer function?

Comment: Actually I did, namely $m =[y]$ and we know $y-1<[y]\leq y$ is true for each $y$.

Comment: Clear enough, thanks

Answer (score -1):

We corrected this in class, and proved it as follow:
$y-x > 1$
$y > x+1$
$[y] > [x+1]$
$[y] > [x] + 1$

And we know that $y-1 \lt [y] \leq y \lt [y] +1$
$\implies y\ge[y]$
Also we know that $x-1 \lt [x] \leq x \lt [x] +1$
$\implies [x]+1\gt x$

So
$y\ge[y] > [x] + 1\gt x$

Therefor
$\exists m \in \{[y], [x]+1\}:y \ge m \gt x$